# WebApplicationInitializer not calling the correct "DispatcherServlet" returning always 404

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, frameworks, dispatcher

I have swtich from working spring MVC application configured with xml's to java configuration with spring boot and I am facing the following behavior. No matter what jsp page I am calling I am always getting the 404 error. The controller is being hit as I can see the sysout messages from the controller printer on the console but no view is being displayed. I have explicitly set the dispatcher mapping to "/" not "/*" but it is still not working.

What i am also seeing and do not know if this is not normal is the output
"No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/WEB-INF/jsp/profile6.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'"

By normal i mean I have registered a dispatcher with the name "dispatcher" not "dispatcherServlet". For me it seems that the dispatcher is not registered correctly, as the sysout "STARTING THE CONFIGURATION" in the onStartup is also not print. Then there is the some  "dispatcherServlet" which is able to print the sysouts from the controller but the view is not beeing found.

Here is the spring boot main function:

```
@ComponentScan("org.syncServer")
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {

ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

System.out.println("PRINTING the beans provided by Spring Boot:");
String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
Arrays.sort(beanNames);
for (String beanName : beanNames) {
System.out.println(beanName);
}

}
}
```

Here is the Initilizer that is extending the WebApplicationInitializer class as per maunual:

```
public class Initializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext)
throws ServletException {
System.out.println("STARTING THE CONFIGURATION");
AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext mvcContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
mvcContext.register(MVCConfig.class);
mvcContext.refresh();

// Register and map the dispatcher servlet
ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet(
"dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(mvcContext));
dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
dispatcher.addMapping("/");
}
}
```

The MVC context :

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "org.syncServer")
@EnableWebMvc
public class MVCConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
registry.addResourceHandler("/pdfs/**").addResourceLocations("/pdfs/");
registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
 }


@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver() {
InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
//resolver.setOrder(2);
resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
return resolver;
}
}
```

my Controller:

```
@Controller
public class ProfileController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/profile6", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String profile6 (){
System.out.println("profile hellow6 has been hit");

return "profile6";

}
```

the profile6 view jsp page

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>this is the greeting jsp profile6 </title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Profile6</h1>
```

the output of the spring boot with tomcat 8.3

```
. ____ _ __ _ _
/\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __ __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
\\/ ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| | ) ) ) )
' |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
=========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
:: Spring Boot :: (v1.0.0.RC3)

.......
.......
2014-02-24 15:23:11.644 INFO 6038 --- [ main] .t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory : Server initialized with port: 8888
2014-02-24 15:23:12.028 INFO 6038 --- [ main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService : Starting service Tomcat
2014-02-24 15:23:12.029 INFO 6038 --- [ main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.3
2014-02-24 15:23:12.171 INFO 6038 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2014-02-24 15:23:12.172 INFO 6038 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4099 ms
2014-02-24 15:23:12.809 INFO 6038 --- [ main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2014-02-24 15:23:18.749 INFO 6038 --- [ main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/get],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String org.syncServer.Controller.REST.Profile.ProfileCont roller.create(org.springframework.ui.Model,org.syn cServer.Model.profile.Profile,org.springframework. validation.BindingResult)
2014-02-24 15:23:18.749 INFO 6038 --- [ main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/profile6],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String org.syncServer.Controller.REST.Profile.ProfileCont roller.profile6()
2014-02-24 15:23:18.749 INFO 6038 --- [ main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/create],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.syncServer.Model.profile.Profile org.syncServer.Controller.REST.Profile.ProfileCont roller.createProfile(java.lang.String,java.lang.St ring)
2014-02-24 15:23:18.750 INFO 6038 --- [ main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/delete],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.util.List<org.syncServer.Model.profile.Profil e> org.syncServer.Controller.REST.Profile.ProfileCont roller.viewjson(org.springframework.ui.Model)
2014-02-24 15:23:18.750 INFO 6038 --- [ main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/hello5],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String org.syncServer.Controller.REST.Profile.ProfileCont roller.hello5()
2014-02-24 15:23:18.750 INFO 6038 --- [ main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String org.syncServer.Controller.REST.Index.profile6()
2014-02-24 15:23:18.788 INFO 6038 --- [ main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping : Mapped URL path [/pdfs/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceH ttpRequestHandler]
2014-02-24 15:23:18.789 INFO 6038 --- [ main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping : Mapped URL path [/resources/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceH ttpRequestHandler]
2014-02-24 15:23:19.372 INFO 6038 --- [ main] o.s.o.h.HibernateTransactionManager : Using DataSource [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@1501e528] of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager
2014-02-24 15:23:19.448 INFO 6038 --- [ main] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler : Initializing ExecutorService 'defaultSockJsTaskScheduler'
2014-02-24 15:23:19.461 WARN 6038 --- [ main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping : Neither 'urlMap' nor 'mappings' set on SimpleUrlHandlerMapping
2014-02-24 15:23:19.614 INFO 6038 --- [ main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2014-02-24 15:23:19.818 DEBUG 6038 --- [ main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Unable to locate LifecycleProcessor with name 'lifecycleProcessor': using default [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecyc leProcessor@55d1c106]
2014-02-24 15:23:19.823 DEBUG 6038 --- [ main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer :



2014-02-24 15:23:34.702 INFO 6038 --- [nio-8888-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2014-02-24 15:23:34.703 INFO 6038 --- [nio-8888-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2014-02-24 15:23:34.725 INFO 6038 --- [nio-8888-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 22 ms
INDEX INDEX has been hit
2014-02-24 15:23:34.853 WARN 6038 --- [nio-8888-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound : No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/WEB-INF/jsp/index.html.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2014-02-24 15:23:34.980 WARN 6038 --- [nio-8888-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound : No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/favicon.ico] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2014-02-24 15:23:34.986 WARN 6038 --- [nio-8888-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound : No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/favicon.ico] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
profile hellow6 has been hit
2014-02-24 15:23:38.423 WARN 6038 --- [nio-8888-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound : No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/WEB-INF/jsp/profile6.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
```

and the pom file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <!--
        The link to the hibernate-validator parent POM only exists out of convenience since we are creating
        this archetype from an existing module of the Hibernate Validator code base.
        If you want to know more about this process check the maven-archetype-plugin documentation
        http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin, epecially the goal create-from-project

        If you want to use this quick-start project as the base for your own application you should remove the
        <parent> entry. See also the other pointers in this pom.
    -->
    <parent>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <version>1.0.0.RC3</version>
    </parent>


    <groupId>sync</groupId>
    <artifactId>syncServer</artifactId>
    <name>syncServer</name>

    <!-- When removing the parent project configuration you have to explicitly set the dependencies version -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
            <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat8.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <defaultGoal>test</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>

            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>6.1.10</version>
                <configuration>
                    <stopPort>9966</stopPort>
                    <stopKey>foo</stopKey>
                      <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>          
                <configuration>
<compilerArgument>-Xlint:unchecked</compilerArgument>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>



        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <!-- When removing the parent project configuration this profile can be removed -->
        <profile>
            <id>archetype</id>
            <activation>
                <file>
                    <exists>archetype.properties</exists>
                </file>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-archetype-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>
                       <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jboss-public-repository</id>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/public</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>springsource-repo</id>
            <name>SpringSource Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.springsource.org/release</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
            <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>

    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
            <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <properties>
        <java-version>1.7</java-version>
        <spring-version>4.0.1.RELEASE</spring-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
        <start-class>org.syncServer.core.Application</start-class>
        <springBootVersion>1.0.0</springBootVersion>
        <tomcat8.version>8.0.3</tomcat8.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>



</project>
```

Comment: I don't know Spring boot well enough, but it seems like it starts up its own Tomcat instance that doesn't do classpath scanning for `ServletContainerInitializer` instances (which lead to your `WebApplicationInitializer`).

Comment: Hello  Sotirios, i am trying understand your idea, but can you be more specific i.e. do you propose to override the ServletContainerInitializee. 
What releates to the classpath scanning i thought it is done by the annotation "@ComponentScan("org.syncServer")"

Comment: The `@ComponentScan` is part of Spring's configuration. A standalone Tomcat instance on the other hand scans the classpath itself to find subclasses of `ServletContainerInitializer`. Spring provides such a class in the form of `SpringServletContainerInitializer` which delegates to your `WebApplicationInitializer` subclass. In this case, it seems the embedded Tomcat instance isn't doing that.

Comment: Can you verify that you have a profile6.jsp file in webapp/WEB-INF/jsp (I am assuming you are using webapp, some may use something else)

Basically I am looking to make sure that your view files are in the correct location.